# Meteor reactivity not working after Blaze update

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a detail page which includes a comments part.
Before the 0.8 upgrade the comments where reactive and reflected the change in minimongo, now they only update when the detail object is updated
The code is the following

detail.html

```
{{#with brick}}
    {{> brick_item}}
    {{> comment_system bind="url" parentType="brick" context=.}}
{{/with}}
```

comments.html

```
<template name="_comment_system">
    <section class="comments">        
        {{#each comments}}
        [...]
        {{/each}}
    </section>
</template>
```

comments.js

```
Template._comment_system.created = function(){
    var bindFilter =  _BindSwitcher[Template._comment_system.bind()()]();
    Template._comment_system.subscription = Meteor.subscribe("comments", bindFilter);
};

Template._comment_system.destroyed = function(){
    Template._comment_system.subscription.stop();
};

Template._comment_system.helpers({
    comments : function(){
        var queryOptions = _.extend({sort: {createdAt: -1}}, Template._comment_system.reactive());
        if(Template._comment_system.subscription.ready())
            return Comments.find({}, queryOptions);
    }
});

_BindSwitcher = {
    'url' : function(){
        return window.location.pathname;
    },
    'data' : function(){
        return 'bind1'
    }
}
[...]
```

The collection and publishing have nothing different from the ordinary.
The problem is that the comments are not reactive. If I insert a comment in mongodb it won't show in the page. If I insert a comment in minimongo it won't show. They appear only after a *brick* is modified.
And if I take the comment system out of the {{#with brick}} the comments will never update, even after changing the *brick*.
Before 0.8 there were no problem with the reactivity.

Can someone point out what I'm missing and if I'm using some feature in a way it was not supposed to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
var queryOptions = _.extend({sort: {createdAt: -1}}, Template._comment_system.reactive());
```

and put this

```
var queryOptions = _.extend({sort: {createdAt: -1}});
```

Comment: I didn't check that part of the code, now I see that it returns {reactive: false}. Strange, I'm sure it was working before.